# Flutter ios stuck at 'Configuring the default Firebase app'

Tags: flutter

I don't want the push notification now, though I have added the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file and code for firebase push notification.

It works on android but having problem in iOS. iOS stuck like this.

[image]

Comment: have you find solution?

Comment: yes, you need follow this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34437#issuecomment-502325212 and it will work nicely

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if it will help now...

I found solution at https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup

It says "Using XCode, move the file into the Runner/Runner directory of your Flutter app."

When, I just copy & paste `GoogleService-Info.plist` at VSCode, and do `flutter run`.
It print "Configuring the default Firebase app" infinitly.

But,

```
1. Execute xcode and open {your_app}/ios
2. drag & drop `GoogleService-Info.plist` at `Runner/Runner`
3. Choose `Finish`
```

this way fixed error.

I hope it will help other people who have same problem.

Answer (score 6):

The [answer](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34437#issuecomment-502325212) should be available here as a quote:

> 1. Open Xcode, then right-click on ***Runner*** directory and select ***Add Files*** to "Runner".
> 2. Select ***GoogleService-Info.plist*** from the file manager.
> 3. A dialog will show up and ask you to select the targets, select the **Runner** target.
> 4. Then add the **CFBundleURLTypes** attributes below into the **[my_project]/ios/Runner/Info.plist** file.

```
<!-- Put me in the [my_project]/ios/Runner/Info.plist file -->
<!-- Google Sign-in Section -->
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <!-- TODO Replace this value: -->
            <!-- Copied from GoogleService-Info.plist key REVERSED_CLIENT_ID -->
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.861823949799-vc35cprkp249096uujjn0vvnmcvjppkn</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<!-- End of the Google Sign-in Section -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding `GoogleService-Info.plist` again through Xcode.

It appears that adding the file in VS Code sometimes doesn't work.